# $\mathbb{R}_{\le3}[X]$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_{\le4}[X]$ (polynomials in linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm sorry that this is probably a stupid question for this page, but I have no one to ask. I'm currently studying linear algebra by myself and I'm confused by this answer:

> $V$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_{\le4}[X]$, because $V$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}_{\le4}[X]$,
>
> where $V := \{ax^3 + bx^2+ cx + d  \in  \mathbb{R}_{\le3}[X] \quad|\quad b = 0\}$

I understand that if it's not a subset it can't be a subspace, but why isn't it a subset?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $R_{\leq 4}[X]$ the space of polynomials of degree $\leq 4$?

Comment: yes (I'm sorry if I wrote it wrongly)

Comment: The indices ought to be exponents. But with that change I would say it's a subset since $V$ is a subset of polynomials of degree at most $3$ and usually one will consider this as a subset of the set of polynomials of degree at most $4$. Everything else would be extremely unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as lisyarus asked, $\mathbb R_{\le n}[x]$ represents polynomials of at most degree $n$ then I somewhat disagree with that solution (and why subscripts as powers??). But here is why I think they *might* claim it. As vector spaces,

$$\mathbb R_{\le 4}[x] \simeq \mathbb R^5$$

Meaning they are isomorphic, or essentially the same space. The polynomial (as a vector) $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ is "essentially the same" as the vector $(a,b,c,d,e)\in \mathbb R^5$. Since there is no mentioned coefficient of $x^4$ I assume they mean it is a fundamentally different thing, just as $(a,b,c) \notin \{(a,b,c,d) \ | a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\}$

However, I interpret $\mathbb{R}_{\le 3}[x]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_{\le 4}[x]$ in the following sense $$\{ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e \ |\  a=0, b,c,d,e\in\mathbb R\}$$

And similarly for $\mathbb R_{\le n}[x]$ for any $n\ge 3$.

Second, since

$$\{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \ |\  b=0\}$$

Is certainly a subspace of $\mathbb R_{\le 3}[x]$, I would also say its a subset of $\mathbb R_{\le 4}[x]$, however my guess at their interpretation from before still stands. But without your explicit definitions and lecture materials I cannot guess any better.

Comment: Very good answer. I'd be surprised at somebody using that convention, but it seems like the most plausible way to make sense of the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

V is not a subset of the space of polynomials of degree <=4 because you can't get a linear combination of the terms of the set to get a complete 4 degree polynomial, since the highest degree in the set is 3, and there's not a second degree, because bx² = 0, since b = 0.